# Fluent Validation, in editing mode, need to fire a rule when the property is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

In editing the values, I have to validate a property1, if the value of property2 is changed.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonType PersonType { get; set; }
    public bool IsVIP { get; set; }
}

public enum PersonType
{
    VIP,
    AnyType1,
    AnyType2
}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.PersonType).Must(CantChangePersonTypeForVIP);
    }

    private bool CantChangePersonTypeForVIP(Person person, PersonType arg)
    {
        // even if PersonType was not changed this method will call and a VIP person validation will always fail
        if (person.IsVIP)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comment, even if PersonType was not changed this method will call and a VIP person validation will always fail.

How can I implement it? Ideally, I was expecting that if PersonType was not changed while editing, it will not call.

I don't know how to implement this.

Am I suppose to hit DB to get the original object to compare?

Comment: Dont you have the `PersonType` object already populated before edit ?

Comment: @Mohammad : do you have any link or example ?

Comment: sorry changetracker is not relevant in your case

Comment: only solution I found is to hit DB and get latest existing value to compare..